# Breakpoints not finding 'row' on NSIndexPath

Tags: ios, debugging

I'm trying to set a conditional breakpoint that only stops at row 74, however, when I set the condition on the breakpoint, it gives me an error saying

```
Stopped dur to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 1.1: "indexPath.row == 74" Couldn't parse conditional expression:
error: property 'row' not foudn on object of type 'NSIndexPath *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

I set the condition like so:

```
indexPath.row == 74
```

Does anyone know why this would happen? Can you not access these properties of NSIndexPath in a breakpoint? I've also tried using the accessor methods instead of dot notation, same error.

Comment: The `row` and `section` properties are from a UIKit category. Try accessing `[indexPath indexAtPosition:0]` (or `1` - I forget whether the `row` is at index `0` or `1`).

Comment: Most likely this has to do with the fact that `row` property is a [UIKit addition to the `NSIndexPath` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSIndexPath/row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. You can do it, but you have to cast them in the first place and use message forwarding. Just like this:

```
(NSInteger)[indexPath row] == (NSInteger)74
```

This will work fine now.

Comment: Wonderful, this works. Would you mind explaining why this cast is needed here? I'm almost certain I've compared indexPath rows before in code and had it work without casting... Although I may not have for all I  know haha

Comment: Well this is due to the way LLVM works. Because when you are creating that condition, basically LLVM is working there, and LLVM is very strict about types and stuff.